# mysql error when inserting post data

Tags: php, mysql

I dont know where my error is in this mysql query

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `events` ( `owner` ,  `title` ,  `tagline` ,  `location` ,  `street` ,  `citytown` ,  `startdate` ,  `enddate` ,  `active`  ) VALUES(  '{$username}' ,  '{$data[title]}' ,  '{$data['tagline']}' ,  '{$data['location']}' ,  '{$data['street']}' ,  '{$data['citytown']}' ,  '{$data['startdate']}' ,  '{$data['enddate']}' ,  '{$data['active']}'  ) "; 
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

It tells my i have an error in the syntax near... and then outputs part of my data where i have apostrophes

(example: title = Dave's Party)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to escape single quotes in your strings before you insert them into the database.

You'll probably want to use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) on each element of your `$data` array.

For example:

```
$escaped_data = array();

foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
    $escaped_data[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($val);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO `events` ( `owner` ,  `title` ,  `tagline` ,  `location` ,  `street` ,  `citytown` ,  `startdate` ,  `enddate` ,  `active`  ) VALUES(  '{$username}' ,  '{$escaped_data[title]}' ,  '{$escaped_data['tagline']}' ,  '{$escaped_data['location']}' ,  '{$escaped_data['street']}' ,  '{$escaped_data['citytown']}' ,  '{$escaped_data['startdate']}' ,  '{$escaped_data['enddate']}' ,  '{$escaped_data['active']}'  ) "; 
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

As an aside, take a look at the PHP documentation for [SQL injection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that you have all values properly escaped.

[mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_escape_string($data['title']);
```

or

```
mysql_real_escape_string($data['title'], $dbconn);
```